# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment using ListFragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am new in Android and trying to make simple App .Im trying to display array list under Fragments . This list keep updated as it is driven by XML data from website . SInce array list is dynamic Im using onActivityCreated rather then onCreateView .
Below are my code

```
package com.example.myearthquake;

public class EarthquakeListFragment extends ListFragment {

  ArrayAdapter<Quake> aa;
  ArrayList<Quake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Quake>();

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<Quake>(getActivity(), layoutID , earthquakes);
    setListAdapter(aa);
    Log.d("EarthQuake","onActivityCreated");
          }
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class Earthquake extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("EarthQuake","Activity");
}
```

Layout

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <fragment android:name="com.paad.myearthquake.EarthquakeListFragment"
 android:id="@+id/EarthquakeListFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Error

```
    01-26 16:12:12.865: D/AndroidRuntime(1480): Shutting down VM
    01-26 16:12:12.865: W/dalvikvm(1480): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught       exception (group=0x41465700)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myearthquake/com.example.myearthquake.Earthquake}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at com.example.myearthquake.Earthquake.onCreate(Earthquake.java:13)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     ... 11 more
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.paad.myearthquake.EarthquakeListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     ... 21 more
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.paad.myearthquake.EarthquakeListFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myearthquake-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myearthquake-2, /system/lib]]
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
    01-26 16:12:12.906: E/AndroidRuntime(1480):     ... 24 more
    01-26 16:17:13.400: I/Process(1480): Sending signal. PID: 1480 SIG: 9
```

Comment: try to be more specific on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Didn't find class "com.paad.myearthquake.EarthquakeListFragment" ...
```

The package name in your code is `com.example.myearthquake` while a class in `com.paad.myearthquake` is attempted to be loaded.

Make sure the XML and code agree on the package names. In here:

```
<fragment android:name="com.paad.myearthquake.EarthquakeListFragment"
```

and here:

```
package com.example.myearthquake;
```