# InflateException because Fragment did not create a view

Tags: android, inflate-exception

I am developing an Android app that I am pushing out to testers using Fabric/Crashlytics.

I have thoroughly tested my app on 2 physical devices myself:

1. Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro running 4.4.2 (API 19)
2. LG G3 running 5.0.1 (API 21)

I have recently pushed out a version of my app to a single tester. Her device is:

- Samsung Galaxy S4 running 5.0.1 (API 21)

I have a login/register `Activity` / `Fragment` series that she is trying to use. I am getting a crash report through Crashlytics, which contains the following information:

Here's an excerpt from the log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.app/com.company.app.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
    ... other lines
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
    ... other lines
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at com.company.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    ... other lines
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.company.app.LoginFragment did not create a view.
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2160)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5610)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
    ... other lines
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at com.company.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    ... other lines
```

Here is a condensed version of my LoginActivity and LoginFragment files:

## activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView />
                <ImageButton />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <FrameLayout>
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.company.app.LoginFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />
            <View />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## LoginActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // This next line causes the error
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ImageButton infoButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.info_button);
    infoButton.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    infoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mUserCreationFragment != null) {
                mUserCreationFragment.showInfo();

            } else if (mEnterCodesFragment != null) {
                mEnterCodesFragment.showInfo();

            } else if (mLoginFragment != null) {
                mLoginFragment.showInfo();

            }
        }
    });
    mToolbar                = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mTitleLabel             = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_label);
    mTitleLabel.setText(getString(R.string.login_string));
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

}
```

## fragment_login.xml

```
<com.company.app.SlidingFrameLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView />
            <Button />
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <EditText />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <EditText />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <Button />
            <Button />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</com.company.app.SlidingFrameLayout>
```

## Line 70 in fragment_login.xml

```
Line 69    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
Line 70    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
Line 71    android:layout_width="match_parent"
Line 72     >
Line 73     <EditText
Line 74        android:id="@+id/password"
Line 75        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
Line 76        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
Line 77        android:inputType="textPassword"
Line 78        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
Line 79        android:layout_width="match_parent"
Line 80        android:maxLines="1"
Line 71        android:singleLine="true"
Line 82        android:textSize="16sp"
Line 83
Line 84        />
Line 85
Line 86    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

## LoginFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView           = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    mPasswordView           = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button registerButton   = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    TextView registerLabel  = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_label);
    mSignInButton           = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mUserNameView           = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    LoginActivity activity  = (LoginActivity)getActivity();
    activity.setLoginFragment(this);

    checkIfComplete();

    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                if (mComplete) {
                    beginLogin();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    mPasswordView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            checkIfComplete();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });

    registerButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    registerButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorTextEnabled));
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EnterCodesFragment fragment = new EnterCodesFragment();
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_from_right, R.animator.slide_out_to_left, R.animator.slide_in_from_left, R.animator.slide_out_to_right)
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment, getString(R.string.basic_information_title_string))
                    .addToBackStack(getString(R.string.enter_codes_fragment_title))
                    .commit();
        }
    });

    registerLabel.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorTextDisabled));

    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            beginLogin();
        }
    });

    Button forgotPasswordButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.forgot_password_button);
    forgotPasswordButton.setPaintFlags(forgotPasswordButton.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    forgotPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final View view         = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.reset_password_dialog, null);

            final EightyPercentDialog dialog = new EightyPercentDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(view);

            final EditText emailEditText  = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text);

            Button cancelButton     = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
            Button okButton         = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);

            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String email    = emailEditText.getText().toString();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    mUserNameView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            checkIfComplete();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
    
    return rootView;
}
```

I've looked at several other posts on here related to `InflateException`, but none of them seem to be applicable to my situation.

For instance:

1. [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369521) seems to be highlighting a problem with package naming, which isn't an issue in my project.
2. [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307672) is dealing with an issue where the order of lines of code is incorrect, which isn't an issue in my project.
3. I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29797172) in an effort to determine whether my issue might be related to using an `AppCompatActivity`, but so far I have not seen anything there that would be problematic.

So, basically, what's confusing me is that I do not have this problem at all on either of my devices, and I don't know Android well enough to see anything on her system (also a Samsung phone running 5.0.1, like mine) that would be problematic. Is there something I'm missing? How can I track down what the actual problem is?

Comment: `LoginFragment did not create a view` Please provide the code where you inflate and set the view in the fragment

Comment: do you use image files whose size is large compared to the size of views you are setting, if yes try resizing those images....

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Added it.

Comment: What is on line 70 in your fragment xml?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi I'll add in that information to my question. Please see edit.